# Next JS prisma error Object literal may only specify known properties and OrderAddress does not exist in type OrderInclude DefaultArgs

Tags: database, next.js, prisma

I'm having some trouble issues to get some data from by database using Prisma. I already tried to update prisma client to the last version, and run npx migrate dev and npx generate prompts but the issue still.

This is the code from my page where is getting the id to get the order resume:

```
import Link from "next/link";

import { Title } from "@/components";
import Image from "next/image";
import clsx from "clsx";
import { IoCardOutline } from "react-icons/io5";
import { getOrderById } from "@/actions/order/get-order-by-id";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";
import { currencyFormat } from "@/utils";

interface Props {
  params: {
    id: string;
  };
}

interface OrderDetails {
  id: string;
  subTotal: number;
  tax: number;
  total: number;
  itemsInOrder: number;
  isPaid: boolean;
  paidAt: Date | null;
  createdAt: Date;
  updatedAt: Date;
  userId: string;
  address: {
    id: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    address: string;
    address2: string | null;
    postalCode: string;
    city: string;
    phone: string;
    countryId: string;
    orderId: string;
  };
  OrderItem: {
    price: number;
    quantity: number;
    size: string;
    product: {
      title: string;
      slug: string;
      ProductImage: {
        url: string;
      }[];
    };
  }[];
}

export default async function OrdersByIdPage({ params }: Props) {
  const { id } = params;

  // Todo: Llamar el server action

  const { ok, order } = await getOrderById(id);

  console.log(  ok, order );

  // if (!ok) {
  //   redirect("/");
  // }

  const orderDetails = order as OrderDetails;
  // const address = orderDetails.address;

  return (
    <div className="flex justify-center items-center mb-72 px-10 sm:px-0">
      <div className="flex flex-col w-[1000px]">
        <Title title={`Orden #${id.split("-").at(-1)}`} />

        <div className="grid grid-cols-1 sm:grid-cols-2 gap-10">
          {/* Carrito */}
          <div className="flex flex-col mt-5">
            <div
              className={clsx(
                "flex items-center rounded-lg py-2 px-3.5 text-xs font-bold text-white mb-5",
                {
                  "bg-red-500": !order!.isPaid,
                  "bg-green-700": order!.isPaid,
                }
              )}
            >
              <IoCardOutline size={30} />
              {/* <span className="mx-2">Pendiente de pago</span> */}
              <span className="mx-2">
                {order?.isPaid ? "Pagada" : "No pagada"}
              </span>
            </div>

            {/* Items */}
            {orderDetails.OrderItem.map((item) => (
              <div
                key={item.product.slug + "-" + item.size}
                className="flex mb-5"
              >
                <Image
                  src={`/products/${item.product.ProductImage[0].url}`}
                  width={100}
                  height={100}
                  style={{
                    width: "100px",
                    height: "100px",
                  }}
                  alt={item.product.title}
                  className="mr-5 rounded"
                />

                <div>
                  <p>{item.product.title}</p>
                  <p>
                    ${item.price} x {item.quantity}
                  </p>
                  <p className="font-bold">
                    Subtotal: {currencyFormat(item.price * item.quantity)}
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))}
          </div>

          {/* Checkout - Resumen de orden */}
          <div className="bg-white rounded-xl shadow-xl p-7">
            <h2 className="text-2xl mb-2">Dirección de entrega</h2>
            <div className="mb-10">
              <p className="text-xl">
                {address!.firstName} {address!.lastName}
              </p>
              <p>{address!.address}</p>
              <p>{address!.address2}</p>
              <p>{address!.postalCode}</p>
              <p>
                {address!.city}, {address!.countryId}
              </p>
              <p>{address!.phone}</p>
            </div>

            {/* Divider */}
            <div className="w-full h-0.5 rounded bg-gray-200 mb-10" />

            <h2 className="text-2xl mb-2">Resumen de orden</h2>

            <div className="grid grid-cols-2">
              <span>No. Productos</span>
              <span className="text-right">
                {order?.itemsInOrder === 1
                  ? "1 artículo"
                  : `${order?.itemsInOrder} artículos`}
              </span>

              <span>Subtotal</span>
              <span className="text-right">
                {currencyFormat(order!.subTotal)}
              </span>

              <span>Impuestos (15%)</span>
              <span className="text-right">{currencyFormat(order!.tax)}</span>

              <span className="mt-5 text-2xl">Total:</span>
              <span className="mt-5 text-2xl text-right">
                {currencyFormat(order!.total)}
              </span>
            </div>

            <div className="mt-5 mb-2 w-full">
              <div
                className={clsx(
                  "flex items-center rounded-lg py-2 px-3.5 text-xs font-bold text-white mb-5",
                  {
                    "bg-red-500": !order!.isPaid,
                    "bg-green-700": order!.isPaid,
                  }
                )}
              >
                <IoCardOutline size={30} />
                {/* <span className="mx-2">Pendiente de pago</span> */}
                <span className="mx-2">
                  {order?.isPaid ? "Pagada" : "No pagada"}
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This another code is my get order by id action:

```
"use server";

import { auth } from "@/auth.config";
import prisma from "@/lib/prisma";

export const getOrderById = async (id: string) => {
  const session = await auth();

  if (!session?.user) {
    return {
      ok: false,
      message: "Debe de estar autenticado",
    };
  }

  try {
    const order = await prisma.order.findUnique({
      where: { id },
      include: {
        OrderAddress: true, // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'OrderAddress' does not exist in type 'OrderInclude<DefaultArgs>'.ts(2353)

        OrderItem: {
          select: {
            price: true,
            quantity: true,
            size: true,

            product: {
              select: {
                title: true,
                slug: true,

                ProductImage: {
                  select: {
                    url: true,
                  },
                  take: 1,
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    });

    if (!order) throw `${id} no existe`;

    if (session.user.role === "user") {
      if (session.user.id !== order.userId) {
        throw `${id} no es de ese usuario`;
      }
    }

    return {
      ok: true,
      order: order,
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);

    return {
      ok: false,
      message: "Orden no existe",
    };
  }
};
```

and finally this is my prisma schema:

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

enum Size {
  XS
  S
  M
  L
  XL
  XXL
  XXXL
}

enum Gender {
  men
  women
  kid
  unisex
}

enum Role {
  admin
  user
}

model Category {
  id      String    @id @default(uuid())
  name    String    @unique
  Product Product[]
}

model Product {
  id          String   @id @default(uuid())
  title       String
  description String
  inStock     Int
  price       Float    @default(0)
  sizes       Size[]   @default([])
  slug        String   @unique
  tags        String[] @default([])
  gender      Gender

  // Relaciones

  category   Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId String

  ProductImage ProductImage[]
  OrderItem    OrderItem[]

  @@index([gender])
}

model ProductImage {
  id  Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  url String

  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId String
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(uuid())
  name          String
  email         String    @unique
  emailVerified DateTime?
  password      String
  role          Role      @default(user)
  image         String?

  address UserAddress?

  // Relaciones
  Order Order[]
}

model Country {
  id   String @id
  name String

  UserAddress  UserAddress[]
  OrderAddress OrderAddress[]
}

model UserAddress {
  id         String  @id @default(uuid())
  firstName  String
  lastName   String
  address    String
  address2   String?
  postalCode String
  phone      String
  city       String

  // Relaciones
  country   Country @relation(fields: [countryId], references: [id])
  countryId String

  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String @unique
}

// Order de compras
model Order {
  id           String    @id @default(uuid())
  subTotal     Float
  tax          Float
  total        Float
  itemsInOrder Int
  isPaid       Boolean   @default(false)
  paidAt       DateTime?

  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt

  // Relaciones
  user   User   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId String

  OrderItem    OrderItem[]
  OrderAddress OrderAddress?
}

model OrderItem {
  id       String @id @default(uuid())
  quantity Int
  price    Float
  size     Size

  // Relaciones
  order   Order  @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id])
  orderId String

  product   Product @relation(fields: [productId], references: [id])
  productId String
}

model OrderAddress {
  id         String  @id @default(uuid())
  firstName  String
  lastName   String
  address    String
  address2   String?
  postalCode String
  city       String
  phone      String

  // Relaciones
  country   Country @relation(fields: [countryId], references: [id])
  countryId String

  Order   Order  @relation(fields: [orderId], references: [id])
  orderId String @unique
}
```

I need to get back all the information related to the order requested by ID.

Thank you!